# How to add Serial Counter for the html table using function

Tags: javascript, html, react-native

i am getting the data by fetching api.
here is after fetching data from API, i am getting data something like this:

```
const info={
    "suggesstion":0,
    "idea":{
       "prod": [
             {
               "group": {
                        "subj": "English",
                        "class": "one",
                        "section": "1A"
                    },
             },
             {
               "group": {
                        "subj": "Physics",
                        "class": "nine",
                        "section": "2A"                      
                    },
             },
             {
               "group": {
                        "subj": "Math",
                        "class": "Ten",
                        "section": "3A"
                    },
             }
          ]
       }
    }
```

Now when i try to call the data in html table, i am using a function so that i can call the values in table together. here is my function.

```
const tableD= info?.idea?.prod.map((info) => {
        const nS= [],
            nC= [],
            nSec= [];
        nS.push(info.group.subj)
        nC.push(info.group.class)
        nSec.push(info.group.section)
     
        let table= [] 
        for (let a in nS) {
            for (let b in nC) {
                for (let c in nSec) {
                                            const nSAll= nS[a],
                                                nCAll= nC[b],
                                                nSecAll= nSec[c];
                                            table+=
                                            `<td>${nSAll}</td>
                                            <td>${nCAll}</td>
                                            <td>${nSecAll}</td>
                                            </tr>`
                                        }
                                    }
                                } 
        return table;
    }).join(' ');

 console.log(tableD);
```

now when i try to use it in html i get this table:
[image]

but i want to add serial number for each row in a column like this here will be 1 ,2 ,3

[image]

here is my html:

```
<table class="demo">
    <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>No</th>
     <th>Subj</th>
     <th>Class</th>
     <th>Section</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>${htmlDatasheet}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

How can i do that in the function, anyone can help me?
Thanks for your trying in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can maintain one variable and use incremented value in each iteration

```
....
let counter = 1; //declare here
const tableD= info.idea.prod.map((info) => {
....
                                table+=
                                        `<td>${counter++}</td> //use here
                                        <td>${nSAll}</td>
                                        <td>${nCAll}</td>
                                        <td>${nSecAll}</td>
                                        </tr>`
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Use *index* variable on the map function to get the index value.

```
const tableD = info?.idea?.prod.map((info, index) => {
  const nS = [],
    nC = [],
    nSec = [];
  nS.push(info.group.subj)
  nC.push(info.group.class)
  nSec.push(info.group.section)

  let table = []
  for (let a in nS) {
    for (let b in nC) {
      for (let c in nSec) {
        const nSAll = nS[a],
          nCAll = nC[b],
          nSecAll = nSec[c];
        table +=
          `<tr>
            <td>${index+1}</td>
            <td>${nSAll}</td>
            <td>${nCAll}</td>
            <td>${nSecAll}</td>
           </tr>`
      }
    }
  }
  return table;
}).join(' ');
```